# How do I code an array and then execute Remove,Length...methods?

Tags: c#, arrays, pipe

I'm a somewhat beginner at this but I'm not sure how to code the array so it will let me use the methods like Trim, StartWith, EndWith, Length...

The error I'm getting is

```
List<string> itemDetails does not contain a definition for 'Trim'
```

(as well as StartsWith, EndsWith, and Length). For the first Remove I'm getting

```
No overload method for 'Remove' takes 2 arguments.
```

The second instance of Remove is fine.

I'm trying to remove the pipe delimiters have the items be displayed in a list box. I haven't formatted the list box yet for these items but there will probably be a tab between each detail of the item and each item will be on a new line. I'm also not too sure if the code I have at the beginning will send what I have to the list box? If you see anything that could be wrong...let me know! Thanks

```
private void frmItemFile_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        items.Fill();
        FillItemListBox();

        List<string> itemDetails = Arrays.asList( " |15324|Packaged|3.38|Cheerios|General Mills| ",
                                 " |15362|Packaged|3.73|Rolled Oats|Quaker| ",
                                 " |19429|Packaged|12.50|Granulated Sugar|B&H| ",
                                 " |67256|Fresh|1.46|Bananas|Dole| ",
                                 " |63851|Fresh|2.29|Apples|Chelan| " );

        itemDetails = itemDetails.Trim();
        if (itemDetails.StartsWith("|"))
            itemDetails = itemDetails.Remove(0, 1);
        if (itemDetails.EndsWith("|"))
            itemDetails = itemDetails.Remove(itemDetails.Length - 1, 1);

        string[] columns = itemDetails.Split('|');
        string itemNumber = columns[0];
        string type = columns[1];
        string price = columns[2];
        string description = columns[3];
        string manufacturer = columns[4];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through each item in itemdetails and call the trim methods on that.

```
 foreach (Var item in itemdetails)
    {
      item = item.Trim();
            if (item.StartsWith("|"))
                item = item.Remove(0, 1);
            if (item.EndsWith("|"))
                item= item.Remove(itemDetails.Length - 1, 1);
    }
```

Comment: it now says for item

    Cannot assign to 'item' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'. But it did remove the errors for them all except the Length.